# Help Solve Recurrence Relation$ T(n) = T(n-1) + O(n)$

Tags: computer-science, recursive-algorithms, recursion

This is how far  I have gotten:

$$T(n) = T(n-1) + O(1)$$
$$T(n-2) = T(T(n-2)) + O(1)) + O(1)$$
$$T(n-2) = T(n-2) + O(2)$$
$$T(n-3) = T(T(n-3) + O(1)) + O(2)$$
$$T(n-3) = T(n-3) + O(3)$$

Finally emerging with this pattern:
$$T(n) = T(n-k) + O(k).$$

Solving for $k$ yields $k = n-1$.

$T(n) = T(n-n-1) + O(n-1)$

$T(n) = O(n)$

Can someone verify my answer and tell me if this is right or wrong?

Comment: Wait, where did you get $T(n)=T(n-1)+O(1)$? That seems wrong.

Comment: If the original formula was $T(n)=T(n-1)+n$, what would you get for a closed form?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I would have O(n) no?

Comment: Really? What is $T(n)=T(0)+1+2+3+4+\dots + n$?